# how to find modal has scrolled to the end -EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, scroll

i'm newbie to emberJS and i want to enable a button when it comes to the scroll end in a modal. so i tried several ways but it didn't work

### View

```
<div class="modal--dialog--body">

    <div class="app_tour--section--terms_container" id="message-container">

      <ul class="app_tour--section--ul">
        <li></li>
           //so many lists to scroll
        <li></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
 import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  didTransition() {
    Ember.run.later('afterRender', () => {
      let objDiv = document.getElementById("message-container");
      if(objDiv.scrollTop == objDiv.scrollHeight)
      console.log(objDiv.scrollTop)
    }, 100);
    return true;
  },


  actions: {

    close: function() {

      this.send('closeModal');
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to getting started with Ember! Like many things, there's a pretty useful addon that will make your life simpler for this: https://github.com/alphasights/ember-scrollable

That provides a scrollable-container and exposes an action when you've reached scroll bottom.

```
{#ember-scrollable onScrolledToBottom=(action "close")}}
  add terms and consitions here
{{/ember-scrollable}}
```

Comment: yeah its a good module but mine didnt work with this cause i have a old version of emberjs where which module not support it

Answer (score 0):

I used  basic jQuery to get the DOM’s element I was targeting and listen to the scroll event with the help of [Rechardo](https://medium.com/@futoricky) and it worked. 
you can check it via her post on medium

https://medium.com/@futoricky/ember-js-detect-scrolling-events-on-html-element-using-component-ac6b2630021a